# Ember Simple Auth: How to set/send multiple request headers?

Tags: ember-simple-auth

I've burned quite a bit of time trying to figure this one out.

My backend is Rails 4.x with devise_token_auth

To authorize a request after login, I need to send multiple headers with each request, like this (verified working with curl):

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" -H "Access-Token: 33YPWz2Kr4eMimYjblDg7w" -H "Client: godv0EDuuc-2qZ6kvrVLzQ" -H "Token-Type: Bearer" -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" -H "Uid: example@gmail.com" -H "Expiry: 1459295877" -H "Provider: Email"  "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/forms"
```

I'm utterly lost as to how the authorize api actually works. I don't see how I can set more than one request header within the DeviseAuthorizer#authorize method.

If someone knows how to do this and can answer the question, I will immediately open a pull request to fix the Ember Simple Auth documentation in this area.

Comment: I was hoping to do this as well. I think the best option its to extend BaseAuthorizer and make a new DeviseTokenAuthorizer based on DeviseAuthorizer's code but with more params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devise authorizer passes a function as the 2nd argument to #authorize.

---

http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/BaseAuthorizer.html#method_authorize

```
authorize(data, block(headerName,headerContent))
```

Arguments

data: Object
The data that the session currently holds

block(headerName,headerContent): Function
The callback to call with the authorization data; will receive the header name and header content as arguments

---

If you want to add your own headers, you can create your authorizer class extending from the devise authorizer. Then override the authorize method like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Devise from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/devise';

export default Devise.extend({
  authorize(data, header) {
    this._super(data, header);

    header('X-Custom-Header', "The custom 1 header");
    header('X-Other-Custom-Header', "The custom 2 header");
  }
});
```

This works because in the data adapter mixin, it is passing this function:

```
this.get('session').authorize(authorizer, (headerName, headerValue) => {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(headerName, headerValue);
});
```

Comment: thanks! one of us should open a PR to add this to the simple auth docs. When i was reading the docs, the concept that was missing was that you could call 'header' multiple times